# Result from Google Search from Mobile is missing amp-analytics element

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

We are facing one issue with the AMP pages coming from Google Search Result in mobile. Google removed `<amp-analytics>` automatically from the website page and Google Analytics is not able to track the clicks.
Our website is [Sportswhy](https://sportswhy.com)

Original AMP page - https://sportswhy.com/amp/

AMP page from Google search - https://www.google.com/amp/s/sportswhy.com/amp/

We are using Astra theme on wordpress with ampforwp plugin for AMP support. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We are also seeing exactly same problem on our site housing.com/news pages. We have no idea what is going wrong

Comment: Traffic is back on track on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the AMPforWP plugin but I do know that if you're using the [official AMP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/) then it strips out any duplicate or invalid `amp-analytics` markup. That is to say if you've inserted any `amp-analytics` markup or script requests within your theme it's possible they may have been removed by the plugin if there were syntax or placement errors.